# Change old WordPress images directory

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, directory-structure

I have a Wordpress installation, but by default everything was uploaded to the "/upload" folder, since this year they are uploaded segmented by folders, I mean it looks like this: "/upload/2020/01/".

I want to change all of them to the same format "(upload / year / month /, how can I do it without stopping seeing the old images?

The issue is that they are more than 9000 and the server has loading problems

Comment: You will not able to do this already existing 9000 images you have there. Reason being the Url us saved to DB. if you can change folder name the url need to be updated as well. But moving forward you can set your own custom upload folder for WP with year and month or etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: every URL of an uploaded file is stored in a database. So you can just change the upload folder or even the folder structure, [your old images will be accessible](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81590/what-happens-to-existing-media-files-when-i-switch-to-year-month-directory-struc). You just have to keep that folder with all your uploads. New files will be uploaded into the new structure.

If you also want to change the structure for the old files...well, this is tricky and I'm not aware of any tool fully automating it, you could do at least software *assisted* migration. There is e.g. [search and replace for WP DBs](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), so you could move the files by hand and update the DB with that tool.

But if you even want to automate the physical change of folders you would have to build a script [as described here](https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-copy-or-move-files-based-on-date-modified-on-linux/) and also update the DB. I do not recomment this because it is very error prone and not easy to test.